# Python saying that module doesn't exist

Tags: python, pip

This question has been asked a lot of times and I can't find an issue that's similar to mine. I was trying to import `consolemenu` which has a member called `SelectionMenu`. But when I try to use it

```py
selected_integer = consolemenu.SelectionMenu.get_selection(option_manager.get_all_keysets())
```

I get an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "---\main.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "---\main.py", line 11, in main
    selected_integer = consolemenu.SelectionMenu.get_selection(option_manager.get_all_keysets())
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'consolemenu' has no attribute 'SelectionMenu'
```

But even intellisense knows it's there! I tried it on another computer and it worked just fine. The python version I'm using is python 3.11.3 and pip 23.0.1.

Comment: It doesn't say the module doesn't exist, it says that the variable doesn't exist in the module.

Comment: Maybe you have an old version of the `consolemenu` module, make sure it's up to date.

Comment: Did you install `console-menu` or `consolemenu`? Different packages, you want to pip install `console-menu`.

Comment: Also just in case make sure there are no local folders named consolemenu

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed! I just needed to install `console-menu` not `consolemenu`.

Answer (score 1):

You might have installed an different module say `pip3 uninstall ConsoleMenu` .
We can check if you have the right packages by `dir(consolemenu)`
it will not have the `SelectionMenu`

I think you mean to use module `pip3 install console-menu`. this one has `SelectionMenu` . see below

```
pip3 install console-menu

>>> import consolemenu
>>> dir(consolemenu)
['ConsoleMenu', 'MenuFormatBuilder', 'MultiSelectMenu', 'PromptUtils', 'Screen', 'SelectionMenu', 'UserQuit', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'clear_terminal', 'console_menu', 'format', 'items', 'menu_component', 'menu_formatter', 'multiselect_menu', 'prompt_utils', 'screen', 'selection_menu', 'validators', 'version']
```